AVD Insights Host Performance Blade Empty after vhange to new Azure Monitoring Agent
I have a question regarding the AVD Insights.
Does anyone else currently have issues with the "Host Performance" blade showing "the query returned no results" for all the insights?
I have this issue currently in multiple of my tenants but can’t find the reason. The environments are a mix of Manual and Terraform deployed. In all of them I recently changed to the new Azure Monitoring Agent.
error
The insights workbook seems to be set up correctly and receives data:
amaconfiguration1 amaconfiguration2 datareceived1 datareceived2
Did any of you experience similar issues and where you able to fix them?
I've already tried:

Recreating the DCR with Terraform and manually
Recreating the DCR with the Microsoft supplied JSON template
Troubleshooting Steps from Microsoft


what did troubleshooting with microsoft/ avd team reveal?

(i'd suggest reaching out to AVD's support team if you haven't already?)

haven't talked to them yet. Will open a ticket today

I found that the only solution for this issue is to create a new log analytics workspace, recreate all session hosts, and connect them to this workspace. This brought the Insights Host Performance back for us in all environments.
Only recreating either law or hosts did not help.

In general, if there's a query in the workbook that doesn't return any rows, edit the workbook, go to that part, and look at the exact query being generated.
Then you can see exactly what table is being queried and what filters/parameters are used, it could be something in the query written by the AVD team is filtering on more than you'd expect, and perhaps they'd need to be involved to fixup the query
